# Convert sRGB color to linear Color Space

Tags: after-effects, color, colorspace

Just wondering if there is a simple and fast way to convert a specific color from my Illustrator layout file (#e3000b) to a linear Color Space.

I am working in After Effects in a linear color space. When I add a new solid and enter my hex code for color, its not the same red as in my layout.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the calculator at http://davengrace.com/dave/cspace/,

Gamma-weighted `#E3000B` translates to linear sRGB `#C50001`

Comment: thank you very much, #C50001 is right! But the converter is some kind of confusing to me, where to you enter the rgb values to get the converted ones?

Comment: Convert your Hex to 0-255 range RGB at http://hex.colorrrs.com/ then input those RGB triplet values into the first row of the site in my answer. The converted values you want will show up on the third row. Multiply each of those values by 256. Round up (or down). Translate back to hex, if needed.